# Fastest, and numerically stable way to compute $CA^{-1}B$ and $CA^{-1}x$?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I have to compute $CA^{-1}B$ and $CA^{-1}x$, where $A,B,C$ are conformable matrices and $x$ is a vector.

I'm not sure if it helps, but $A$ is symmetric and positive definite. The $A$ matrix will be of dim approximately $100 \times 100$ and not sparse...

I've read that the a very numerically stable way to compute these inverses is by computing the Cholesky Decomposition.

How would we, in Mathematica, compute the expressions above in the fastest way possible, using a numerically stable method? It can be through Cholesky or any other method.

Comment: Do you happen to need that for [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of a symmetric saddlepoint matrix? In that case [this survey](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/MBenzi-p2.pdf) is a must-read.

Comment: Any extra information about $x$ that we can use? Or totally arbitrary?

Comment: @MikeY it's arbitrary...

Answer (score 8):

In general, you may use the following for computing $C \, A^{-1} \, x$:

```
sol = LinearSolve[a]; 
c.sol[x]
```

Here, `sol` is `LinearSolveFunction` object which stored a suitable factorization; this factorization can also be reused. Per default, it is an `LU`-factorization.

In case that `a` is symmetric positive-definite or Hermitian positive-definite, you can enforce to use a Cholesky factorizaion as follows:

```
sol = LinearSolve[a, Method -> "Cholesky"];
```

You can also apply `sol` to matrices, so $C \, A^{-1} \, B$ can be computed with

```
c.sol[b]
```

Of course, `sol[b]` will take much longer than `sol[x]` because `sol` has to be applied to each column of `b`. So if you can, avoid it.

If matrix $A$ is not too large but still ill-conditioned, you may also consider to use `c.PseudoInverse[a].b`. `PseudoInverse` employs (I guess) singular value decomposition (with truncation of singular values up to some tolerance) and thus can deal also quite well with very ill-conditioned matrices. `PseudoInverse` is rather expensive and will generate a dense matrix in general. So it is not well-suited for sparse matrices. If you know a priorily that the singular values of `a` decay rapidly, you can employ a truncated SVD (using only a limited number of the largest singular values); with the Arnoldi method, this might also be doable for certain sparse matrices.

```
rank = 10;
{U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[a, rank, Method -> "Arnoldi"];
c.(U\[Transpose].(1/Diagonal[Σ] V.b))
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to use perconditioners in *Mathematica*'s Arnoldi methods which really limits their usefulness for large sparse matrices.

Comment: Henrik, in your answer, it seems you didn't end up explaining how one can enforce a Cholesky factorization with linear solve...

Comment: Hah! You're right (of course). Please see my edit.

Comment: Henry, thanks for it. However, I was also looking for a faster way to compute those expressions than just using Inverse... 

I've used AbsoluteTiming, and the linearsolve method is a bit worse...

Comment: What kind of matrix is `A`? E.g., is is exact (i.e., integers) or does it have floating point numbers?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Floating point numbers.

Comment: If you decompose it into two matrices (Cholesky decomposition) then you are tossing in a multiplication step vice just sucking it up and computing $A^{-1}$ once. This answer suggests you are out of luck without some other structure in the problem. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82858/fast-multiplication-of-constant-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-and-vector